# Vaadin 23 Confirm Dialog free or not

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

ConfirmDialog is not marked as commercial feature any more https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/confirm-dialog but Vaadin 23.1.7 still shows the Commercial warning message.

So ConfirmDialog is free or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component was recently made [free](https://github.com/vaadin/platform/pull/3174) and is probably scheduled for 23.2, but as of now, there is no official statement or roadmap entry for it.

Comment: That's correct – ConfirmDialog will be free from V23.2 onwards. This will be mentioned in the release notes.